# How to find text on a webpage and copy the text in the adjacent section

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I need to find a location on the webpage by the visible text. Then I need to copy the value that is adjacent to it. It makes more sense when you see the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]
So the idea is to find the text "Net PPW" and then grab the value, which for this example is "1.56".

I assume this is possible since they are in the same section of the webpage but I have no clue how to do this or where to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simpliest solution is mannually check every p element text on page to get next argument with p tag in result(cause they always stay together).

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')

for x in range(len(elements)):
     if elements[x].text == "Net PPW"
         print(elements[x+1].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of XPath you can locate the parent element based on it's parent and then locate the parent element, as following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'justify-content-between')][contains(.,'Net PPW')]//p[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-body1')]").text
```